# javascript not working with IE

Tags: javascript

My page is working fine with FF , but not working under IE ,

I have a JSP page and a JS file (The error is inside JS File)

I am using IE developer toolbar 
Its only showung me the Line number and the character.

Please see the screen shot .

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=3bc4916

MY JSP file is of only 20 lines and JS file is of 200 lines , with many 3rd party JS files included.

How can we debug as i dont have that line number in my JSP FIle and view source doesn't help.

Please help me

Comment: can you post the code... it will make easy for others to check

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 8 has a built in debugger. You can find instructions for how to use it here [JScript Debugger in IE8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jscript/archive/2008/03/13/jscript-debugger-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx).

Basically, if you enable this, then you can actually go look at the code and see where the problem is.

The debugger can not only show you the code, but also a snapshot of the variables at the time the error occurs. Using this information, you can further pinpoint the problem.